# How to capture combination of keys( CTRL+ALT + SPACE) in WPF RichEdit control

Tags: wpf, key, combinations

i want to capture key combination such as ALT+CTL+SPACE in my RichEdit control in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

You can add  `PreviewKeydown` event for `RichTextBox`.

```
PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_OnPreviewKeyDown" in xaml
```

event handler in code behind as follows

```
private void TextBox_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) && 
        Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Space))           
    {
        //  All keys were pressed
    } 
}
```

you can test when three keys are pressed.